# Spark Dataset: CompileException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am parsing a CSV file into spark SQL dataset with a specific format. Some of these entities I want to map into another very simple format.

```
// First Format
case class Foo(...)

// Second Format
case class Bar(..., rating: Rating)
case class Rating(value: Double) extends AnyVal

// Transformation
def asBar(f: Foo): Option[Bar]
```

This transformation works perfectly fine with `Lists`. But when I try to do the same with spark's `Dataset` the execution fails due to an Exception:

org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 85, Column 30: Assignment conversion not possible from type "double" to type "*.*.*.Rating"

```
// this works fine
List[Foo](...).flatMap(asBar)

// this fails
Dataset[Foo](...).flatMap(asBar)
```

If anyone is wondering: I am creating the `Rating` type to make sure it satifies some restrictions on the more general `Double` type.